# How can I apply custom filter by default while launching Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request

For example: I am interested only in C, C++, and Python tags. I created custom tags for each and apply whenever I need it. Now I want to make one of the custom tags default (load questions only of that tag) when Stack Overflow launches.

Is it possible?

Comment: *created custom tags* ... do you mean Watched and Ignored tags?

Comment: @rene: similar, but Watched tags just highlights the mentioned tag questions in group of all questions. What I want to see only those highlighted questions, not others.

Comment: Just save a search for `intags:mine`: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3amine%20is%3aq

Comment: Just add all other tags to your Ignored tags and set in your profile that ignored tags should be hidden.

Comment: @rene: I thought about that, but an easier way should be there right?

Comment: right ... no, not really.

Comment: @rene: I found one issue with that. For eg: apache-arrow would be one of the tags I would have added in Ignored tag, but I found out there is question which has both c++ and apache-arrow, it gets ignored though c++ is in watched tags. So user could have any possible tags combinations in their quesitons.

Comment: I fail to see how that’s a problem. If you don’t know anything or don’t care about [apache-arrow], then you aren’t going to know or care about [apache-arrow] when it’s being used with [c++].

Comment: True. But I think questions can be entirely c++ issue, but it could get discovered during [apache-arrow] usage and it gets tagged with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can. I have a few custom filters though and they show up by on the sidebar, and I generally watch those for new content I'm interested in (a red dot shows up when new questions show up under that filter that I haven't viewed yet):

[image: Custom Filters]

Of course, you can also set watched tags for tags I am interested in as well that show up by default, but more complex filtering I think has to be done with a custom filter. I do think though that being able to set a custom filter as your default filter would be a useful feature.